# Why useSWR doesn't retrieve cache when the fetcher uses a Bearer token?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, caching, react-hooks, swr

In my React Native app, I utilize the useSWR hook and have set up the SWRConfig to fetch cached data when offline. This setup works seamlessly for all my API calls, except for one specific case.

Here's the scenario:

1. While online, I initiate an API call that requires a Bearer token for authentication.
2. I then switch to offline mode and perform a full app reload.
3. Upon doing so, useSWR understandably throws a Network Error since I'm offline.
   However, the issue is that the data remains undefined, even though the cached data is
   present in storage.

Interestingly, this anomaly seems to arise only when I use a Bearer token (which isn't expired) with the fetcher.

Here is the SWRConfig component which wraps my app:

```
 <SWRConfig
            value={{
              fetcher: (url) => fetcherAxios(url),
              refreshInterval: 0,
              provider: () => cache,
              onSuccess: (data, key) => {
                rootStore.configStore.setIsNetworkUp(true)
                storeDataInCache(data, key)
              },
              onError: async (error) => {
                if (
                  Logger.getErrorMessage(error) === NetworkError ||
                  Logger.getErrorMessage(error) === NetworkRequestFailed
                ) {
                  rootStore.configStore.setIsNetworkUp(false)
                } else if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
                  await clearAuthToken()
                  rootStore.cleanStore()
                  Alert.alert(translate("alert.connectionExpire"))
                } else {
                  Logger.logAndRethrow(error)
                }
              },
            }}
          >
```

Here is the fetcher:

```
export const fetcherAxios = (url) => {
  try {
    return axios.get(url).then((response) => response.data)
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.logAndRethrow("error fetcherAxios")
  }
}
```

Here is the API call:

```
export const useAd = () => {
  let query = `frontpage`
  const { data } = useSWR(API_ADS_BASE_URL + query)
  return data?.data
}
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Are there any known solutions or workarounds? I'd greatly appreciate any insights or assistance. Thank you.